# Is it possible to exclude transaction from the voting inside transactionscope?

Tags: .net, ado.net, transactionscope

Every transaction inside the scope of transactionscope votes for commit. And TS works as all ore nothing.

I want to wrap several methods with transactionscope.

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    DoSomething1();
    DoSomething2();

    ts.Complete();
}
```

Both methods open connections and try to commit. They try several times to recreate connection with transaction in case of deadlock timeouts. Hence I need to exclude failed transactions from voting and leave the successful one.

Comment: I'd see the comment of the downvoter what he didn't like about this question.

Answer (score 2):

Put the retry logic outside of the `TransactionScope`. You cannot exclude operations after they have been executed. You have to decide transaction membership before you execute an operation.

You can of course start independent transactions using `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` but they will be independent of the outer `TransactionScope` which makes the outer `TransactionScope` useless.

Also, there is no way to avoid a deadlock from killing the transaction. This is required by principle to remove locks from the deadlock graph. The correct way to deal with a deadlock is to retry the whole transaction, nut just a part of it or even a single statement. That would lead to incomplete effects.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are made to work as "All or nothing", and they have to be ACID compliant. If you want to allow failed transaction, then it is no longer transactional operation, it is part of business logic and it should be rewritten for that.

You can supress a transaction as mentioned in [TransactionScopeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Suppress: The ambient transaction context is suppressed when creating the scope. All operations within the scope are done without an ambient transaction context.

**Connection and Context Lifecycle**

Calling multiple methods that process multiple logic involving opening multiple connections to same database must be rewritten to invoke entire logic with just one connection and one context. If each method will be invoked inside a transaction then why are you creating transaction in each method?

Comment: SQL Server supports partial rollbacks (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178157(v=sql.105).aspx) I see no reason why this cannot exist for transaction scope

Comment: And here is the sort of explanation why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412635/alternative-to-save-point-when-using-system-transactions