# Will this transaction be rolled back if errors happens

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a transaction I want to commit but unsure if it will be rolled back if anything fails. I know I can use a TransactionScope in c# and if an error occurs everything will be rolled back. But I am not so sure about a transaction in a stored procedure. All the examples online have a roll back with the `ROLLBACK` keyword. What if I dont have a ROLLBACK keyword then what will happen?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePost
    @type INT,
    @name VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @insertedId TABLE(Id INT)
    DECLARE @id INT

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO [Post] ([Name], [Type])
    OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @insertedId
    VALUES (@name, @type)

    UPDATE [Tables] SET Ordinals =ordinals + 1
    WHERE Id = @tableId

    COMMIT
END
```

Comment: This question is not a duplicate to the chosen post. I am merely asking if the above stored procedure will roll back automatically if an error occurs.

Comment: Reopened. I don't think this is a duplicate question of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421770/using-transactionscope-around-a-stored-procedure-with-transaction-in-sql-server).

Comment: You could have created a small test that would have given you the answer in less time than it took to ask this.  Keep that in mind next time you have a question about how something simple behaves.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, transaction automatically gets rolled back if it doesnt reach `COMMIT` statement.**

Here is a simple example

sample table

```
create table tt(id int)
```

sample procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePost
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO tt values (1)

    select cast('ldfsfds' as int)

    COMMIT
END
```

Execute the procedure and query the table

```
EXEC CreatePost    
select * from tt
```

result

```
0 records
```

The end result will be an empty table, assuming there were no records before execution of procedure.

Comment: Might want to actually run the stored proc in your example

Comment: @JoePhilllips : Corrected. :)

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure runs in its own connection context and the connection will close when procedure ends .
As you have explicitly started a transaction, if any error happens and code does not reach to commit statement, it will rollback automatically.